# mount file to Kubernetes Pod Without Deleting the Existing Project Files?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to deploy a Magento app in Kubernetes. my PHP pod contains my custom image which contains cloned repository from git. but since I need my webserver (nginx) to access .conf file inside my project  I created a shared PVC called dir.
but when running my php pod all the files inside my containers gets deleted.

I will show you an example when executing `kubectl exec <pod id> -- it` :

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: dir
      
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dir
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: nessrinehafi/tajerpro_phpfpm:latest
        volumeMounts:
          - name: dir
            mountPath: /var/www/html
```

i get this :
[image]

but when I change my yaml file like this :

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: dir
  
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dir
  containers:
  - name: php
    image: nessrinehafi/tajerpro_phpfpm:latest
```

[image]
I get all my files but I can't connect my project to Nginx.
please if anyone faced a similar error help me.

Comment: I think I'm a little confused on what happens here.  Are these two PNG files things that are served by the image?  And if you mount a volume over `/var/www/html`, the PNG file that's in the persistent volume gets served, and if you don't mount the volume, a different PNG file (stored in the Docker image?) gets served instead?

Comment: If you mount a volume on to a directory, it hides everything that's in that directory; you _only_ see the contents of the volume.  If the volume is empty then it will hide the contents from the original image.  Nothing automatically copies content into a volume in Kubernetes.

Comment: @DavidMaze the second image is when i remove   volumeMounts from Yaml file and it displays the files that exist inside my image.

Comment: @DavidMaze so do i need to find a way to copy my directory inside my volume ?

Comment: If it's a PHP application, and `/var/www/html` contains your actual application, you need to not mount a volume there at all.

Comment: but when i do not my Nginx pod can't reach magento.conf file.